# Minimizing, maximizing exe's

Tags: python

How do I maximize, minimize, check whether the program is minimized ?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Are you talking about your own program? If so, what toolkit are you using (tkinter, wxpython, etc). Or, are you talking about controlling other programs? If so, what platform are you on?

Comment: It's a game, gta san andreas to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip through the win32gui module (part of the [PyWin32 extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)).  Most of the functions in it are fairly thin wrappers of standard [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468919%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) calls.

If you want to blindly control something, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790825/how-can-i-maximize-a-specific-window-with-python).

Checking if your target program is maximized/fullscreen could likely be accomplished by `win32gui.`[`GetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28VS.85%29.aspx) and checking that handle.