# Speed/efficiency comparison for loop vs list comprehension vs other methods

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension

Using the example codes I give below, I would like to have a better understanding of how python speed varies depending on how I structure a given function.

The example functions I define work as follow: given two strings they return the number of digits that they differ. We assume that `assert len(s1) == len(s2)` is always true.

First function uses a list comprehension.

```
def h_dist1(s1,s2):
    return sum(dgt1 != dgt2 for dgt1, dgt2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

Second function uses a classic for loop.

```
def h_dist2(s1,s2):
    tot = 0
    for d1, d2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if d1 != d2:
            tot += 1
    return tot
```

The complexity of the second code is clearly `O(N)` where `len(s1)=len(s2)=N`.

*Example related question:* Is there a better way to define this particular function? What's the complexity of `h_dist1`?

*General question:* What's, in general, the best (in terms of: readability, speed, efficiency, more pythonic) way of defining a function that is similar to the ones given in the example above (i.e. that need to loop over a string/array/etc)? And, *most important, why is a particular way the most fast/efficient*?

**Note** I have looked for similar questions but I haven't found anything specific, e.g. in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24175322/4003492) HYRY says that to speed up a code one should use 1. local variables in for loop and 2. use list comprehension. **But I still don't understand why**. Of course, any reference to other Q/A is welcome.

Comment: The complexity is *exactly the same*; they are both `O(N)`. Differences in performance (have you tried to `timeit`?) are not related to the complexity.

Comment: I am going to test the speed. Any insight on how to improve efficiency in general (also using different methods, perhaps)?

Comment: If you're dealing with large iterables, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is worth a look. But you should write working, readable code first, then profile and optimise only if there's a performance issue.

Comment: FWIW, your `h_dist1()` uses a generator expression. A list comprehension would look like: `return sum([dgt1 != dgt2 for dgt1, dgt2 in zip(s1, s2)])`; note the square brackets.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, you are right. As I understand the generator expression method should be better (in terms of memory) that the list comprehension one. Is this right?

Comment: @rafforaffo the genexp will use less memory than the list comp, yes, but may be slower.

Comment: @rafforaffo: What jonrsharpe said. Also, setting up a genexp needs a little bit of memory, so for very small lists it makes sense to use a list comprehension instead. Also, in some cases, the function processing the output of the genexp needs to turn that output into a list before it can start processing, so using a genexp doesn't even save you memory. The classic example is `''.join(genexp)` vs `''.join([listcomp])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be too quick to write off the humble `for` loop. If you don't actually need a list, like in this case, a standard `for` loop can be faster than using a list comprehension. And of course it has less memory overheads.

Here's a program to perform timing tests; it can be easily modified to add more tests.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Time various implementations of string diff function

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/28581218/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.02.18
'''

from itertools import imap, izip, starmap
from operator import ne

from timeit import Timer
from random import random, seed

def h_dist0(s1,s2):
    ''' For loop '''
    tot = 0
    for d1, d2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if d1 != d2:
            tot += 1
    return tot

def h_dist1(s1,s2):
    ''' List comprehension '''
    return sum([dgt1 != dgt2 for dgt1, dgt2 in zip(s1, s2)])

def h_dist2(s1,s2):
    ''' Generator expression '''
    return sum(dgt1 != dgt2 for dgt1, dgt2 in zip(s1, s2))

def h_dist3(s1,s2):
    ''' Generator expression with if '''
    return sum(1 for dgt1, dgt2 in zip(s1, s2) if dgt1 != dgt2)

def h_dist3a(s1,s2):
    ''' Generator expression with izip '''
    return sum(1 for dgt1, dgt2 in izip(s1, s2) if dgt1 != dgt2)

def h_dist4(s1,s2):
    ''' imap '''
    return sum(imap(ne, s1, s2))

def h_dist5(s1,s2):
    ''' starmap '''
    return sum(starmap(ne, izip(s1, s2)))

funcs = [
    h_dist0,
    h_dist1,
    h_dist2,
    h_dist3,
    h_dist3a,
    h_dist4,
    h_dist5,
]

# ------------------------------------

def check_full():
    print 'Testing all functions with strings of length', len(s1)
    for func in funcs:
        print '%s:%s\n%d\n' % (func.func_name, func.__doc__, func(s1, s2))

def check():
    print 'Testing all functions with strings of length', len(s1)
    print [func(s1, s2) for func in funcs], '\n'

def time_test(loops=10000, reps=3):
    ''' Print timing stats for all the functions '''
    slen = len(s1)
    print 'Length = %d, Loops = %d, Repetitions = %d' % (slen, loops, reps)

    for func in funcs:
        #Get function name and docstring
        fname = func.func_name
        fdoc = func.__doc__

        print '\n%s:%s' % (fname, fdoc)
        t = Timer('%s(s1, s2)' % fname, 'from __main__ import s1, s2, %s' % fname)
        results = t.repeat(reps, loops)
        results.sort()
        print results
    print '\n' + '- '*30 + '\n'

def make_strings(n, r=0.5):
    print 'r:', r
    s1 = 'a' * n
    s2 = ''.join(['b' if random() < r else 'a' for _ in xrange(n)])
    return s1, s2

# ------------------------------------

seed(37)

s1, s2 = make_strings(100)
#print '%s\n%s\n' % (s1, s2)
check()
time_test(10000)

s1, s2 = make_strings(100, 0.1)
check()
time_test(10000)

s1, s2 = make_strings(100, 0.9)
check()
time_test(10000)

s1, s2 = make_strings(10)
check()
time_test(50000)

s1, s2 = make_strings(1000)
check()
time_test(1000)
```

The results below are from a 32 bit 2GHz Pentium 4 running Python 2.6.6 on Linux.

**output**

```
r: 0.5
Testing all functions with strings of length 100
[45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45] 

Length = 100, Loops = 10000, Repetitions = 3

h_dist0: For loop 
[0.62271595001220703, 0.63597297668457031, 0.65991997718811035]

h_dist1: List comprehension 
[0.80136799812316895, 1.0849411487579346, 1.1687240600585938]

h_dist2: Generator expression 
[0.81829214096069336, 0.82315492630004883, 0.85774612426757812]

h_dist3: Generator expression with if 
[0.67409086227416992, 0.67418098449707031, 0.68189001083374023]

h_dist3a: Generator expression with izip 
[0.54596519470214844, 0.54696321487426758, 0.54910516738891602]

h_dist4: imap 
[0.4574120044708252, 0.45927596092224121, 0.46362900733947754]

h_dist5: starmap 
[0.38610100746154785, 0.38653087615966797, 0.39858913421630859]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

r: 0.1
Testing all functions with strings of length 100
[13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13] 

Length = 100, Loops = 10000, Repetitions = 3

h_dist0: For loop 
[0.59487199783325195, 0.61918497085571289, 0.62035894393920898]

h_dist1: List comprehension 
[0.77733206748962402, 0.77883815765380859, 0.78676295280456543]

h_dist2: Generator expression 
[0.8313758373260498, 0.83669614791870117, 0.8419950008392334]

h_dist3: Generator expression with if 
[0.60900688171386719, 0.61443901062011719, 0.6202390193939209]

h_dist3a: Generator expression with izip 
[0.48425912857055664, 0.48703289031982422, 0.49215483665466309]

h_dist4: imap 
[0.45452284812927246, 0.46001195907592773, 0.4652099609375]

h_dist5: starmap 
[0.37329483032226562, 0.37666082382202148, 0.40111804008483887]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

r: 0.9
Testing all functions with strings of length 100
[94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94] 

Length = 100, Loops = 10000, Repetitions = 3

h_dist0: For loop 
[0.69256496429443359, 0.69339799880981445, 0.70190787315368652]

h_dist1: List comprehension 
[0.80547499656677246, 0.81107187271118164, 0.81337189674377441]

h_dist2: Generator expression 
[0.82524299621582031, 0.82638883590698242, 0.82899308204650879]

h_dist3: Generator expression with if 
[0.80344915390014648, 0.8050081729888916, 0.80581092834472656]

h_dist3a: Generator expression with izip 
[0.63276004791259766, 0.63585305213928223, 0.64699077606201172]

h_dist4: imap 
[0.46122288703918457, 0.46677708625793457, 0.46921491622924805]

h_dist5: starmap 
[0.38288688659667969, 0.38731098175048828, 0.38867902755737305]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

r: 0.5
Testing all functions with strings of length 10
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] 

Length = 10, Loops = 50000, Repetitions = 3

h_dist0: For loop 
[0.55377697944641113, 0.55385804176330566, 0.56589198112487793]

h_dist1: List comprehension 
[0.69614696502685547, 0.71386599540710449, 0.71778011322021484]

h_dist2: Generator expression 
[0.74240994453430176, 0.77340388298034668, 0.77429509162902832]

h_dist3: Generator expression with if 
[0.66713404655456543, 0.66874384880065918, 0.67353487014770508]

h_dist3a: Generator expression with izip 
[0.59427285194396973, 0.59525203704833984, 0.60147690773010254]

h_dist4: imap 
[0.46971893310546875, 0.4749150276184082, 0.4831998348236084]

h_dist5: starmap 
[0.46615099906921387, 0.47054886817932129, 0.47225403785705566]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

r: 0.5
Testing all functions with strings of length 1000
[506, 506, 506, 506, 506, 506, 506] 

Length = 1000, Loops = 1000, Repetitions = 3

h_dist0: For loop 
[0.59869503974914551, 0.60042905807495117, 0.60753512382507324]

h_dist1: List comprehension 
[0.68359518051147461, 0.70072579383850098, 0.7146599292755127]

h_dist2: Generator expression 
[0.7492527961730957, 0.75325894355773926, 0.75805497169494629]

h_dist3: Generator expression with if 
[0.59286904335021973, 0.59505105018615723, 0.59793591499328613]

h_dist3a: Generator expression with izip 
[0.49536395072937012, 0.49821090698242188, 0.54327893257141113]

h_dist4: imap 
[0.42384982109069824, 0.43060398101806641, 0.43535709381103516]

h_dist5: starmap 
[0.34122705459594727, 0.35040402412414551, 0.35851287841796875]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: thanks, do you know the reasons for the differences in performance among the various functions you tested?

Comment: @rafforaffo: Some of the speed improvements are due to what Ashwini Chaudhary mentioned at the start of his post: avoid doing loops in Python and let a module function do it using compiled (i.e. C) code. However, many modules are written in Python so you don't automatically get a speed improvement simply by using a module function. Note that some of these speed differences depend on the data, eg with the functions that sum lists those that avoid collecting zeroes into the list are much faster if there are lots of zeroes, but are actually slower if there are few zeroes.

Comment: @rafforaffo: Other things that affect speed are the time overhead in function calls and in method / attribute lookups. Calling a function bound to a local name will be faster than calling `modname.funcname()`. Also note that these timings are implementation-dependant, to a degree, and you'll probably get quite different relative timings if you run these tests on non-standard Pythons. So please don't take these results as an ultimate guide to which function is better. If you are concerned with speed, do your own tests, using realistic data.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the Python loops as much as possible and don't create unnecessary lists in memory, following these things you can get a very efficient solution. For example `zip` creates a list in memory, so we can use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to get an iterator. So, `sum(starmap(ne, izip(s1, s2)))` is the fastest one as per my quick tests:

```
>>> from itertools import imap, izip, starmap
>>> from operator import ne
>>> s1 = 'a'*10**5
>>> s2 = 'b'*10**5
>>> %timeit sum(starmap(ne, izip(s1, s2)))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.25 ms per loop
```

Few other solutions:

```
>>> %timeit sum(imap(ne, s1, s2))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.08 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sum(dgt1 != dgt2 for dgt1, dgt2 in zip(s1, s2))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sum(1 for dgt1, dgt2 in zip(s1, s2) if dgt1 != dgt2)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sum(dgt1 != dgt2 for dgt1, dgt2 in izip(s1, s2))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.02 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sum(1 for dgt1, dgt2 in izip(s1, s2) if dgt1 != dgt2)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.17 ms per loop
```

But the differences are not huge, so I would personally use `izip` with a generator expression without abusing the fact that True == 1 and False == 0 in Python:

```
sum(1 for dgt1, dgt2 in izip(s1, s2) if dgt1 != dgt2)
```

Comment: The `sum(1 for ... )` variants should have even more of a speed advantage if the strings mostly match, since they avoid passing zeroes to `sum()`.