# Speed up code that doesn't use groupby()?

Tags: python, lambda

I have two pieces of code (doing the same job) which takes in array of `datetime` and produces clusters of `datetime` which have difference of 1 hour.

First piece is:

```
def findClustersOfRuns(data):
    runClusters = []
    for k, g in groupby(itertools.izip(data[0:-1], data[1:]),
                        lambda (i, x): (i - x).total_seconds() / 3600):
        runClusters.append(map(itemgetter(1), g))
```

Second piece is:

```
def findClustersOfRuns(data):
    if len(data) <= 1:
        return []
        current_group = [data[0]]
        delta = 3600
        results = []

        for current, next in itertools.izip(data, data[1:]):
            if abs((next - current).total_seconds()) > delta:
                # Here, `current` is the last item of the previous subsequence
                # and `next` is the first item of the next subsequence.
                if len(current_group) >= 2:
                    results.append(current_group)

                current_group = [next]
                continue

            current_group.append(next)

        return results
```

The first code takes 5 minutes to execute while second piece takes few seconds. I am trying to understand why.

The data over which I am running the code has size:

```
data.shape
(13989L,)
```

The data contents is as:

```
data
array([datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 9, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 10, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 9, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 10, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 11, 0)], dtype=object)
```

How do I improve the first piece of code to make it run as fast?

Comment: Why downvote, can you please explain?

Comment: I believe it is due to the usage of lambda

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the reason for the massive time difference, but FWIW, using literal tuples in function args is deprecated, and not permitted in Python 3, so your `lambda (i, x): ...` won't work in Py3. Also, you shouldn't use `next` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `next` function. It won't hurt here, but it is confusing to people reading your code.

Comment: One of the first things you should do when optimizing a piece of code is profile it to determine where it spends most of its time. See [_How can you profile a Python script?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the size, it looks you are having a huge `list` of elements i.e. huge `len`. Your second code is having just one `for` loop where as your first approach has many. You see just one right? They are in the form of `map()`, `groupby()`. Multiple iteration on the huge list is adding huge cost to the time complexity. *These are not just additional iterations, but also these are slower than the normal `for` loop.*

I made a comparison for another post which you might find useful [Comparing list comprehensions and explicit loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39518977/2063361).

Also, the usage of `lambda` function is adding up extra time.

However, you may further improve the execution time of the code by storing `results.append` to a separate variable say `my_func` and make a call as `my_func(current_group)`.

Few more comparisons are:

- [Python 3: Loops, list comprehension and map slower compared to Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36261621/2063361)
- [Speed/efficiency comparison for loop vs list comprehension vs other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28584157/2063361)