# Maximize Sublime Text window with python

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am trying to make a Sublime Text 3 plugin to loop through the Sublime Text windows and maximize each one.

I am looping through the windows like this but, after searching the web for a few hours, I do not know how to maximize the window.

```
import sublime
for window in sublime.windows():
```

Comment: window.run_command("toggle_full_screen")

Comment: I do not want full screen. I want to maximize the window.

Comment: U should use [win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790825/how-can-i-maximize-a-specific-window-with-python)

Comment: SmartManoj Thanks for the comment, but I no longer use sublime or windows. If you post a decent answer, I will accept it.